# Ubuntu 16.04 distro/backup has only live boot options and no install

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, live-usb, remastersys

I have a distro/backup iso both made with `PinGuy builder` and when I boot the usb no install option on the menu just `live` and `memtest`.

Tried to boot with

```
live live-install
```

no suceess there.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Maybe the person who made the custom iso forgot to install the installer (no pun intended). Maybe the iso file is intended to run live (and not to install Ubuntu). I suggest that you download a standard Ubuntu iso file (or a community flavour Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu), create a USB boot drive from it and install Ubuntu (or a community flavour), https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what helped me overcome the issue:

1. Run the live boot
2. Run the installation shortcut

   **or** open the terminal and run:

   `sudo sh -c 'ubiquity gtk_ui'`

It's good to have internet access while installing so it downloads all the dependencies of the distro/backup.

Good luck